# Django-paypal "POST /notify/ HTTP/1.0" 500 59

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

```
   [31/Mar/2015 12:20:55] "POST /notify/ HTTP/1.0" 500 59
```

I get this error and no more. signal simple not connect

```
   @csrf_exempt
   def showme(sender,  **kwargs):
       ipn_obj = sender
       if ipn_obj.payment_status  == "Completed":
         user_profile = auth_user.objects.get(id=ipn_obj.custom)
         if user_profile.balance==None:
         user_profile.balance = float(10)
         else:
         user_profile.balance += float(10)
         user_profile.save()

  payment_was_successful.connect(showme)
```

My notify url

```
   @csrf_exempt
   def notify(request):
       payment_was_successful.connect(showme)
       return HttpResponse('OK4')
```

Comment: I hope that's not your actual whitespace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX the error by manually added notify url  logic

```
@csrf_exempt
def notify(request):
    if request.POST.get("payment_status")  == "Completed":
     user_profile = auth_user.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("custom"))
     if user_profile.balance==None:
     user_profile.balance = float(10)
     else:
     user_profile.balance += float(10)
     user_profile.save()
     return HttpResponse('OK4')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. can you please show your models .. I need it urgently.. thanks for your kind support